# MySQL case insensitive search on varbinary field?

Tags: mysql, search, varbinary

I have a varbinary field id like to do a case-insensitive search on.

I know that the way varbinary fields work prohibits you from doing something like so:

```
WHERE LOWER(page_title) = LOWER("Gasket")
```

So is there a way to do this? I imagine I could temporarily cast the field as a varchar or something. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-convert.html) function:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CONVERT(page_title USING latin1) = 'gasket';
```

See also [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html)