# SQL string does not work -> SQL LOWER

Tags: mysql, sql, lowercase

Table `page`:

```
| id | page_title |

| 1 | John_Lennon |
```

Select:

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE LOWER(page_title) = 'john_lennon';
```

I want to have the row with `page_title = 'John_Lennon'`.
I don't know why, but it does not work. In phpmyadmin it returns `null`.

Comment: Try this, 
SELECT * FROM page WHERE page_title LIKE '%john_lennon%';

Answer (score 1):

There could be extra spaces present in that column data and so it's not matching. Try using `TRIM()` function as well along with `LOWER()` like

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE TRIM(LOWER(page_title)) = 'john_lennon';
```

Comment: It returns also null :/

Comment: Can you post you table schema/definition? looks like a problem with `collation`

Comment: LOWER() might not do what you expect against a VARBINARY column, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807839/mysql-case-insensitive-search-on-varbinary-field